# JQuery make hyperlink based on Text of Anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following table & what is the best way to make the cell of table `<td>` clickable/hyperlink based on the text it has.

```
<table id="fresh-table" class="table">
    <thead>
        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
        <th data-field="URL" data-sortable="true">URL</th>
        <th data-field="Results">Results</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href="#">https://google.com</td>
            <td>Woot</td>
        </tr>     
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href="#">https://facebook.com</td>
            <td>Hax</td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $('.clickme').getText();
    console.log(x);
});
```

I would like to replace the values of `href` based on text it got ex: 
`https://google.com` or `https://facebook.com`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyNdrZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that your HTML is invalid; you're missing the `</a>` tags to close the anchors within the `table`.

Secondly, jQuery has no `getText()` method. I would assume you meant to use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text) instead.

With regard to your question, you can use `prop()` to set the `href` attribute of the `a` elements equal to their `text()`. The simplest way to do this is to provide a function to `prop()` which will be executed on each element in the collection. Try this:

```js
$('#fresh-table a').prop('href', function() {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fresh-table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
    <th data-field="URL" data-sortable="true">URL</th>
    <th data-field="Results">Results</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="#">https://google.com</a></td>
      <td>Woot</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="#">https://facebook.com</a></td>
      <td>Hax</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that without `jQuery` in just few lines of code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  for (const element of document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#']")) {
    element.href = element.innerText;
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRgqxB